# Generate serial of character

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, ascii

How to generate serial character without char I and O in postgresql?

With the code:

```
select chr(a) 
from generate_series(ascii('A'),ascii('A')+10-1,1) a
```

this code include char I but i don't want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just filter it?..:

```
t=#  select chr(a),a from generate_series(ascii('A'),ascii('A')+10-1,1) a 
where a not in (73,79);
 chr | a
-----+----
 A   | 65
 B   | 66
 C   | 67
 D   | 68
 E   | 69
 F   | 70
 G   | 71
 H   | 72
 J   | 74
(9 rows)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.